# IPv6 still used even Network Manager IPv6 set to "Ignore"

Tags: networking

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 (via Wubi). When IPv6 is set to "Ignore" with Network Manager, the machine still creates an auto-configured address and will use it (for example Firefox accessing http://www.google.com) instead of using the IPv4 address. Am I missing anything ?

I know that there are other ways to disable IPv6, but still would like to understand the meaning of this "Ignore" option.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). I would disable IPv6 via another method.

Comment: The machine can not get any global IPv6 address unless you have configured one machine in your lan to announce and route an global IPv6 net.  The link local address, fe80::/10, will only be used on your link, in your lan.
You have some other problem.